# How to create pandas dataframe automatically from nested for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

This is a purely fictional example, but it demonstrates what I need.  My current code that gets the results I want, but I would like to write a nested `for` loop to create lists / dataframes automatically without hard coding (or whatever can reduce hard-coding).

In this case, I have data that has columns for Age Group and Gender.  I want to create a stacked barchart with Plotly for each Age Group, broken down by Gender.  Also, I'm using pandas to massage the data.

The problem I'm having is that either Age Group and Gender could change.  For example, the current data set has Age Groups: 20s, 30s, 40s, 50s, 60s, 70s, 80s, 90+, but other age groups can be added in the future (90s, 100s, 110s, etc.) so I would have to go back and add these in manually.

Similarly, the current data set has genders: female, male, unspecified, but other categories can be added in the future.  If a new gender category is added, I would have to go back into the code and add it in manually as well.

```py
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

# source = "https://data.ontario.ca/dataset/f4112442-bdc8-45d2-be3c-12efae72fb27/resource/455fd63b-603d-4608-8216-7d8647f43350/download/conposcovidloc.csv"
df = pd.read_csv("conposcovidloc.csv")

# Age_Group = ['<20', '20s', '30s', '40s', '50s', '60s', '70s','80s', '90+', 'UNKNOWN']
Age_Group = df["Age_Group"].unique().tolist()


# Client_Gender = df["Client_Gender"].unique().tolist()

count_female = []
count_male = []
count_unspecified = []
count_diverse = []

for age in Age_Group:
    count_female.append(df[(df["Age_Group"]==age) & (df["Client_Gender"]=="FEMALE")]["Age_Group"].count())
    count_male.append(df[(df["Age_Group"]==age) & (df["Client_Gender"]=="MALE")]["Age_Group"].count())
    count_unspecified.append(df[(df["Age_Group"]==age) & (df["Client_Gender"]=="UNSPECIFIED")]["Age_Group"].count())
    count_diverse.append(df[(df["Age_Group"]==age) & (df["Client_Gender"]=="GENDER DIVERSE")]["Age_Group"].count())

trace1 = go.Bar(x=Age_Group, y=count_female, name="Female", marker={"color": "#FFD700"})
trace2 = go.Bar(x=Age_Group, y=count_male, name="Male", marker={"color": "#9EA0A1"})
trace3 = go.Bar(x=Age_Group, y=count_unspecified, name="Unspecified", marker={"color": "#CD7F32"})
trace4 = go.Bar(x=Age_Group, y=count_diverse, name="Gender Diverse", marker={"color": "#000000"})

data = [trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4]
layout = go.Layout(title="Ontario COVID-19 Case Breakdown by Age Group and Gender", barmode="stack")

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
pyo.plot(fig, filename="bar.html")
```

I was thinking maybe doing something like this to get a new dataframe

```py
df2 = []

for age in Age_Group:
    for gender in Client_Gender:
        count_female.append(df[(df["Age_Group"]==age) & (df["Client_Gender"]==gender)]["Age_Group"].count())
        df2.append()

trace = go.Bar(x=Age_Group, y=Client_Gender, name=Client_Gender)
```

Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way completely.

Edit: I've almost got it, thanks to @samir-hinojosa with the advice of using globals().  Here's my revised code that is almost what what I need.  My `for` loop looks like its being replicated multiple times, and I'm not sure why.

```py
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

url = "https://data.ontario.ca/dataset/f4112442-bdc8-45d2-be3c-12efae72fb27/resource/455fd63b-603d-4608-8216-7d8647f43350/download/conposcovidloc.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)

Age_Group = df["Age_Group"].unique().tolist()
Client_Gender = df["Client_Gender"].unique().tolist()

data = []
for gender in df["Client_Gender"].unique():
    globals()["count_" + gender] = []

for gender in Client_Gender:
    for age in Age_Group:
        globals()["count_" + gender].append(df[(df["Age_Group"]==age) & (df["Client_Gender"]==gender)]["Client_Gender"].count())
        trace = go.Bar(x=Age_Group, y=globals()["count_" + gender], name=gender)
        data.append(trace)

layout = go.Layout(title="Ontario COVID-19 Case Breakdown by Age Group and Gender") # Remove barmode to get nested 

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
pyo.plot(fig, filename="html/bar.html")
```

The numbers and shape of the chart look correct, but the legend shows gender multiple times, not sure how to fix this. There should only be 4 genders in the legend.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `globals()`. You can see an example below

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexisperrier/intro2nlp/master/data/openclassrooms_intro2nlp_sentiment_vegetables.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df.head()

tweet_id    search_keyword  sentiment   text    neg pos
0   1340355010299908096 parsnip 1   @user @user All the best @user you cheeky litt...   0.009569    0.874337
1   1340093851143450624 green beans 1   RT @user @user lamb chops , green beans , maca...   0.001479    0.966661
2   1340089889984012290 eggplant    1   @user I make the best eggplant parmesan 0.002113    0.955990
3   1340053955792035840 yams    0   They candied yams go stupid!    0.918229    0.011744
4   1339085046548897792 spinach 0   @user Cooked spinach. Just kidding that stuff ...   0.871717    0.014765

df["search_keyword"].unique()

array(['parsnip', 'green beans', 'eggplant', 'yams', 'spinach', 'celery',
       'leek', 'carrot', 'tomato', 'chickpea', 'avocado', 'asparagus',
       'mushroom', 'cabbage', 'kale', 'lettuce', 'quinoa', 'potato',
       'onion', 'cucumber', 'rice', 'cauliflower', 'brocolli', 'turnip',
       'lentils', 'pumpkin', 'corn', 'okra', 'radish', 'artichoke',
       'squash', 'garlic', 'endive', 'zuchinni'], dtype=object)
```

In this case, I am going to create dinamically several dataframe based on the `search_keyword` list

```
for search_keyword in df["search_keyword"].unique():
    globals()["df_" + search_keyword] = df[df["search_keyword"]==search_keyword]
```

Now, you can access each dataframe based on the name `"df_" + df["search_keyword"].unique()`

```
df_eggplant.head()

tweet_id    search_keyword  sentiment   text    neg pos
2   1340089889984012290 eggplant    1   @user I make the best eggplant parmesan 0.002113    0.955990
33  1340284341449076736 eggplant    1   Just guys no the later today? only using a bit...   0.009440    0.838516
62  1338954692173258753 eggplant    1   @user Oh wow, lucky eggplant!   0.003778    0.946546
182 1338889204575526919 eggplant    0   RT @user destyal hotfuck 27cm. Fucked. Gand ... 0.885911    0.013338
308 1339045305027686403 eggplant    0   bachelorette BacheloretteABC TheBacheloretteAB...   0.980897    0.002719
```

In the same way, you can access each dataframe with `globals()`. For example:

```
my_dataframes = ['parsnip', 'mushroom', 'cauliflower']

for dataframe in my_dataframes:
    display(globals()["df_" + dataframe].head(3))


tweet_id    search_keyword  sentiment   text    neg pos
0   1340355010299908096 parsnip 1   @user @user All the best @user you cheeky litt...   0.009569    0.874337
350 1340251679149744129 parsnip 0   @user It is worse than Martin Heidegger. My br...   0.875097    0.011754
541 1340426164188237825 parsnip 1   New burger invention? Cheesy parsnip latkes wi...   0.002752    0.946687

tweet_id    search_keyword  sentiment   text    neg pos
14  1338944115279495168 mushroom    0   @user Trump has never "administered" anything ...   0.913989    0.006175
20  1339156461327437824 mushroom    1   @user You'd probably be more careful than me a...   0.006338    0.960806
35  1340401530864873479 mushroom    1   This Creamy Mushroom Chicken Pasta is so cream...   0.002506    0.980949

tweet_id    search_keyword  sentiment   text    neg pos
39  1339992494025617410 cauliflower 0   @user @user no love for the cauliflower   0.841673    0.011049
63  1340349399529119745 cauliflower 1   Grab yourself a delicious dinner today @user "...   0.001387    0.921891
92  1340344141012750336 cauliflower 1   A comfort food classic, this Cauliflower, Panc...   0.000985    0.968648
```

Comment: Thanks, the `globals()` got me much further.  I've added a screenshot of my issue with the `for` loop, any ideas how to correct this?

Comment: @Peter look at the new answer that I wrote.

Comment: Thanks again!  This answers my question.  I just forgot to indent one of my statements in my `for` loop.  Everything is working great now! `Globals()` is definitely useful for this!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your needs, I suppose that you are looking for something as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

url = "https://data.ontario.ca/dataset/f4112442-bdc8-45d2-be3c-12efae72fb27/resource/455fd63b-603d-4608-8216-7d8647f43350/download/conposcovidloc.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)

df_temp = df[["Row_ID", "Age_Group", "Client_Gender"]].groupby(["Age_Group", "Client_Gender"]).count().reset_index()
df_temp.columns = ["Age group", "Client gender", "Value"]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
plot = sns.barplot(x="Age group", y="Value", hue="Client gender", data=df_temp, ax=ax1)
plt.title("Comparison of age group and client genders", size=20)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.004, 1), borderaxespad=0, title="Client gender")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.xlabel("Age group", size=12)
plt.ylabel("Client gender", size=12)
#plt.savefig("img/comparison.png")
sns.despine(fig)
```

[image]

If you want to verify

```
df[(df["Client_Gender"]=="FEMALE") & (df["Age_Group"]=="20s")].shape
(112076, 18)

df[(df["Client_Gender"]=="MALE") & (df["Age_Group"]=="20s")].shape
(106093, 18)

df[(df["Client_Gender"]=="FEMALE") & (df["Age_Group"]=="50s")].shape
(70978, 18)

df[(df["Client_Gender"]=="MALE") & (df["Age_Group"]=="50s")].shape
(64816, 18)
```

You can notice that the values seem to be ok.